# console returning not function when function is defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want `backAgain` to be executed 2 secs after clicking button `stopCrash` but console is returning error: Uncaught TypeError: this.backAgain is not a function

any ideas?

```js
methods:{
    backAgain(){
      this.winning = 0;
      this.betAmount = 0;
      this.moneyValue = null;
    },
    cashOut(){
      clearTimeout(this.tessst);
      this.money = Number(this.money) + Number(this.winning);
      setTimeout(function(){
        this.backAgain()
      },2000)
    }}
```

```html
<button class="stopCrash" @click="cashOut">Cash out</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all because you're loosing `this` when you set a timeout, because `function(){}` doesn't save the `this` context, but as arrow functions do, check the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable/34361380#34361380) between them

```
setTimeout(() => this.backAgain(), 2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an arrow function in order to access `this` context :

```
  cashOut(){
      clearTimeout(this.tessst);
      this.money = Number(this.money) + Number(this.winning);
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.backAgain()
      },2000)
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `this`. Arrow function does it for you.
If you are using IE 11 and you don't have arrow functions, you can bind in this way:

```
setTimeout(function(){ this.backAgain() }.bind(this), 2000)
```

In your case, you can bind and execute with `call` or `apply` execute:

```
setTimeout(this.backAgain.call(this), 2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is lost when the callback is called, but you can for example use a local variable in its closure (the usual concept of accessing variables from "outer" blocks surrounding a piece of code extended with the "twist" that the variables can be accessed even after the immediate code which contained them has finished running), which is not lost:

```
cashOut(){
  clearTimeout(this.tessst);
  this.money = Number(this.money) + Number(this.winning);
  var diz = this;             // <--- store
  setTimeout(function(){
    diz.backAgain();          // <--- use
  },2000)
}}
```